# clean repeated code in C++ constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a header file in c++ that provides several constructors for user(it is a requirement):

```
#ifndef IMANDEL_H_
#define IMANDEL_H_

class IMandel{

public:
    IMandel();
    IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength);
    IMandel(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength);
    //other stuff!
private:
    int max_iterations, thread_count, height, width;
    int* buffer; 
};

#endif
```

Therefore in my corresponding cpp file I have these constructors implemented respectively:

```
//default constructor
IMandel::IMandel(){
    height = 10000;
    width = 10000;

    //this code segements gets repeated in every constructor! Messy!
    max_iterations = 255;
    thread_count = 1;
    buffer = new int[width*height];
}

IMandel::IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength){
    width = aWidth;
    height = aLength;

     //this code segements gets repeated in every constructor! Messy!
    max_iterations = 255;
    thread_count = 1;
    buffer = new int[width*height];
}

IMandel::IMandel(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength){
    thread_count = threads;
    width = aWidth;
    height = aLength;

     //this code segements gets repeated in every constructor! Messy!
    max_iterations = 255;
    buffer = new int[width*height];
}
```

As you can see, my constructors are not healthy, they have repeated chunks of code everywhere, and that is terrible!

In java , I found a solution to this problem by using constructors call each other. Basically I re-use the constructors like the following (Java example):

```
public myClass(){
    this(1, 10000, 10000);
}

public myClass(int aWidth, int aLength){
   this(1, aWidth, aLentgh);
}

public myClass(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength){
   thread_count = threads;
   width = aWidth;
   height = aLength;
   max_iterations = 255;
   buffer = new int[width*height];
}
```

As you can see int this Java example, there is no repeated code amongst the various constructors. 
Questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve this same effect in C++?
2. If so how? Can you provide a sample?
3. If not, what solution do you recommend to fix the problem?

Comment: Delegating constructors are part of C++11. Also, you can use in-class member initialization in C++11 if all of them initialize a member to the same value by default (and override it if necessary).

Comment: @chris: I'm kinda newbie at this, you'll have to be a more specific please. Can you provide an example?

Comment: First of all, you'll have to compile with `-std=c++11` on a compiler that supports the feature. Then change `this` to `myClass` and put it in the constructor initializer list (denoted by a colon following the parameter list).

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix You could also move your `thread` argument to the end and use default arguments with a single constructor. Or can you not change the header?

Comment: you can also move the common code in another method.

Comment: @chris: I am not sure if the machine where the code is going to be re-compiled supports the feature. It is probably an old one.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I can change the headers, but I don't think that solved my problem. I'll still have repeated code all over the place.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I don't think I explained very well. Praetorian has added an answer showing what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The practical solution varies, depending on which version of C++ you are using.

**In C++03**, a common *(but imperfect - see useful comments at the bottom)* approach is to create an `init()` function that all the constructors call.  All three of your constructors could be a single line calling a function like this:

```
void IMandel::init(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength){
    thread_count = threads;
    width = aWidth;
    height = aLength;

     //this code segements gets repeated in every constructor! Messy!
    max_iterations = 255;
    buffer = new int[width*height];
}

//default constructor
IMandel::IMandel(){
    init( 1, 10000, 10000 );
}

IMandel::IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength){
    init( 1, aWidth, aLength );
}

IMandel::IMandel(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength){
    init( threads, aWidth, aLength );
}
```

**In C++11**, constructors are allowed to call other constructors, as @chris commented.  You could change your constructors in this manner:

```
//default constructor
IMandel::IMandel()
: IMandel( 1, 10000, 10000 )
{
}

IMandel::IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength)
: IMandel( 1, aWidth, aLength )
{
}

IMandel::IMandel(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength){
    thread_count = threads;
    width = aWidth;
    height = aLength;

     //this code segements gets repeated in every constructor! Messy!
    max_iterations = 255;
    buffer = new int[width*height];
}
```

Comment: the `init` function solution doesn't support data members that can't be default constructed, or whose default constrution is costly.

Comment: @Drew Dormann: thanks, how do I know which compiler version my deployment machine uses? Is there any UNIX debian command to easily check that?

Comment: Important point about init functions: member variables have already been constructed when init function is called. This only matters for member objects (not pointers) where constructor does important stuff, but it is still something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix it depends on the compiler.  Current versions of gcc, for example, support both versions and C++11 is enabled if gcc is run with command-line parameter `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 3):

What solution to adopt depends on the concrete case.

Here's your current class definition:

```
class IMandel
{
public:
    IMandel();
    IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength);
    IMandel(int threads, int aWidth, int aLength);
    //other stuff!
private:
    int max_iterations, thread_count, height, width;
    int* buffer; 
};
```

Here's how I would define it:

```
class IMandel
{
public:
    IMandel( int aWidth = 10000, int aLength = 10000, int threads = 1 );
    //other stuff!
private:
    int max_iterations, thread_count, height, width;
    std::vector<int> buffer;
};
```

Note that this still gives you the *apparent* constructors that you originally had, except for argument order.

There's no need to make things more complicated than necessary, that is, **KEEP IT SIMPLE**. Other C++03 means include, however, a common `init` function (when that is applicable, not here), and a common artifical base class. Other C++11 means include constructor forwarding.

---

In passing, note that your original code violated the "rule of three", i.e. it needed to either disallow or explicitly support copying, but failed to do that. The simpliciation presented above does not suffer from that problem. Can you see why?

Comment: +1... I edited what I *believe* to be a typo.  (Please review)

Comment: @DrewDormann: well having all arguments defaulted to 0 was not a typo, but either way is fine. with your edit the interface documents what the default values are. but this comes at the cost of client code having to specify at least *some* value for e.g. `aWidth` if it's desired to specify `threads` (say).

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11's delegating constructors that can reduce having duplicate code in constructors. In your case though, it seems you just need to provide default values for your constructor arguments.

```
#ifndef IMANDEL_H_
#define IMANDEL_H_

class IMandel{

public:
    IMandel(int aWidth = 10000, int aLength = 10000, int threads = 1);
private:
    int max_iterations, thread_count, height, width;
    int* buffer; 
};

#endif

IMandel::IMandel(int aWidth, int aLength, int threads)
: max_iterations(255)
, thread_count(threads)
, height(aLength)
, width(aWidth)
, buffer(new int[width*height])
{
}
```

The above constructor does everything the 3 you've shown do. Also, consider using a `vector<int>` for `buffer` instead of managing the memory yourself.